# Contains method behavior on enums collection in Java

Tags: java, collections, enums

can anybody explain to me why contains method returns false in following code?
I have two collections of the same type. A hint might be that items of these collections looks in the tab differently. The globalRoles wariable is something that is deserialized from json (by Jackson library). The origin of variable "role" is actually hardcoded value in this case
I have intentionaly expanded code to multiple steps so all the values of variables are visible.
[image: Debug snapshot]

Comment: Code as text please!

Comment: Most probably you haven't defined hashcode and equals

Comment: Please share how you have defined Role

Comment: [I downvoted because you're being unresponsive to comments](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive), and because [images of code are not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: Snapshot is used to capture variables state and memory structures. Hardbto describe it only using text. Also wantend to capture breakpoint position...

Comment: I will describe the solution in response, now I have found the problem. It is not related to equals or hashcode. The sad part is that those guys giving negativ points actually do not understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the solution and what was wrong. The getGlobalRoles() returns value that is actually initialized in mapper that is written in Groovy. The problem was that Groovy assigned Arralist to variable of List without any exception. The variable was explicitly typed so I havent expected this behavior. Usually exception is thrown in these cases. Then Java went just crazy because of list of strings behind a variable of different type. So it was not related to contains method or equals or so... Most of operations with this collection went wrong, when I have tried them.